nothing happens when connecting to sqlite database in react native
I am trying to open sqlite database following some tutorials, but nothing happens after writing the code. no error message, the following is my code, please see what I am missing. one thing I want
to add that I am setting up page navigation
here is my code
import { StatusBar } from 'expo-status-bar';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, Button, Alert } from 'react-native';
import * as SQLite from "expo-sqlite";
import { Asset } from 'expo-asset';


const db = SQLite.openDatabase(
    {
        name: "book",
        location: "default",

    },
    () => { },
    error => { error.console.log(error) }
);

export default function App() {
    const selectfrom = () => {
        db.transaction((tx) => {
            tx.executeSql(
                "SELECT * FROM questions;",
                console.log(JSON.stringify(rows))
            )
        })
    }
    return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
            <Text>this is the first page</Text>
            <StatusBar style="auto" />
        </View>
    );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex: 1,
        backgroundColor: '#fff',
        alignItems: 'center',
        justifyContent: 'center',
    },
});

